# Substituir o list() colocando valor em cada índice de um array

Tags: php, array, variáveis, lista

Então, eu estava navegando pelo php.net quando me deparei com o List() e fui ver para quê servia. Aí eles me deram o seguinte exemplo:

```
$info = array('Café', 'marrom', 'cafeína');
list($bebida, $cor, $substancia) = $info;
echo "$bebida é $cor e $substancia o faz especial.\n";
```

Nessa eu me pergunto: Não da de eu, ao invés de fazer isso, fazer tipo:

```
$info = [$bebida, $cor, $substancia]; 
aí fazer tipo 
$info[0] = "café"
$info[1] = "marrom"
$info[2] = "cafeína"
```

E depois só chamar num `echo` da vida tipo `"$info[0] é $info[1] e $info[2] o faz especial. \n"`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A capacidade da função `list` vai muito além. Há a capacidade de manusear `arrays` maiores, em casos mais específicos que seu código venha a depender. Eu considero que o `list`, além de poder ser usado e abusado, tem a capacidade de deixar o código mais semântico.

Seu exemplo ficaria mais semântico se:

```
<?php
$frase = "café marrom cafeina";
list($bebida, $cor, $substancia) = explode(" ", $frase);

if ($cor == 'marrom') {
    $cor = 'preto';
}

echo sprintf("%s é %s e %s o faz especial.", $bebida, $cor, $substancia);
```

Logo, convenhamos que `$info[1]` o sujeito precisa voltar pra cima no código, interpretar o `array` e então, entender que a chave `1` é na verdade é uma variável com o atributo `cor`. Logo, desse modo o código perde a chance de ser mais compreensível.

Meu exemplo não é dos melhores, mas minha intenção com a resposta é te dizer que não só por que você tem um meio mais "comum" de fazer as coisas, que esse meio seja o melhor a ser usado. Pesquise, estudo, investigue, amadureça seu código.

Comment: Bom exemplo +1.

Comment: Aaaah, eu sempre tenho dificuldade de entender o porquê das coisas no php porque não consigo ter dimensão disso sendo usado numa rede social, por exemplo. Algum código grande. Nos exemplinhos de 5 linhas que acho na internet, não tenho noção de "pq isso facilita as coisas?". Obrigada por responder, vou pesquisar mais profundamente sobre o list e ver ele aplicado em grandes projetos. Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

O comando `list` cria de um determinado `array` uma lista de variáveis em um operação simples e única, é um facilitador na hora de programar, mas, nada impede utilizar cada posição do `array` para imprimir valor, como você o fez no exemplo.

Isso são formas possíveis no desenvolvimento com [php](/questions/tagged/php), é muita vezes util em determinados cenários, como tudo em desenvolvimento de sistema.

Esse comando também pode ser utilizado para `array` `simples` ou `bidimensionais`.

**Array simples:**

```
$info0 = array('um', 'dois');
list($a1,$a2) = $info0;
echo $a1; // um
echo $a2; // dois
```

**Array bidimensionais:**

```
$info1 = array(array('versao', 'forma'), array('razão', 'cultura'));
list($b0, $b1) = $info1;
var_dump($b0); //    
//array(2) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(6) "versao"
//  [1]=>
//  string(5) "forma"
//}
var_dump($b1); //
//array(2) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(6) "razão"
//  [1]=>
//  string(7) "cultura"
//}
```

ou seja, ele extrai de cada posição de um `array` para `variáveis` simples para facilitar na codificação do seu `script`.

É sempre bom conhecer as alternativas e muita vezes dando manutenção em código de terceiros não ser surpreendido com esse tipo de ***codificação***.

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [list](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.list.php)
- [PHP list() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_list.asp)
- [PHP 5 Array Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp)

Comment: É exatamente o que estou estudando. Percebi que tem muitas formas de fazer várias coisas no php. Mas ainda estou iniciando e estou tentando diferencias situações e saber em qual momento eu uso tal código. Obrigada pelo suporte!